# didReceiveRegistrationToken / didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function not calling for iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios13

I am using Firebase to send push notification. To get FCM token I am trying fetch FCM token.`But for iOS 13 didReceiveRegistrationToken/didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function not calling.`
It is working fine for iOS 12. Facing issue for iOS 13 devices.

I have done:

1. The project contains GoogleService-Info.plist.
2. I have no issues with certification and provisioning profiles. Push notification configured for bundle id and provisional profile.
3. It is working fine for iOS 12 devices.
4. Capabilities:
   i. Backend mode enable for remote notification.
   ii. Push notification enable.

Comment: please add your details code of `didReceiveRegistrationToken/didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function` here